# Создание элемента перед элементом jquery

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

как мне создать элемент перед другим элементом, если их родитель - определённый класс. Я пытался сделать вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').parent('.home').before('<br>');
});
```

В данном случае мне нужно вставить перед ссылкой `<br>`, но данный код не даёт результатов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подправить и все...

```js
$(_ => {
  $('.home a').before('<br>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='home'>
  <p>как мне создать элемент перед другим элементом, если их родитель - <a href='#'>определённый класс</a>. Я пытался сделать вот так
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div>mydiv</div>").insertBefore('.mobile-sub .s2_error')
```

ИЛИ написав другой селектор внутри вашего insertBefore

Передавать

```
$('.revive').parent(".mobile-sub").prepend('<div>mydiv</div>');
```

Comment: Сделай исполняемый вариант ответа. Использую данные похожие на данные из вопроса ТС...

Answer (score 0):

Пример c использованием `css`

```css
.home a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='home'>
  <p>как мне создать элемент перед другим элементом, если их родитель - <a href='#'>определённый класс</a>. Я пытался сделать вот так
  </p>
</div>
```